# How can I omit zsh completions from the scrollback buffer?

Tags: terminal, zsh, autocomplete

I have a zsh configuration with auto-completion ([auto-fu](https://github.com/hchbaw/auto-fu.zsh)) and the option `no_always_last_prompt`, which will re-print the prompt and the current command line buffer below completions.

Is there a way not to include completions in the scrollback buffer and keep the prompt to the bottom of the screen while editing the command line?

I would like to:

- make it work in the linux console, but I'm ok with tmux or [dvtm](https://github.com/martanne/dvtm), so if I could display completions in another pane, that could be acceptable;
- "clear" completions from the scrollback buffer, perhaps from the `precmd` hook function, form completion widgets and upon `accept-line`;
- modify the `clear-screen` widget to print `$LINES` empty lines and then `zle .reset-prompt && zle -R` (I'll also try to replace `/usr/bin/clear`)

I'm thinking to use escape sequences to automatically delete the required number of lines to get rid of printed completions and somehow scroll or re-print the prompt at the bottom. Note that I'd like to preserve previous command output lines. They should be visible above completions.

Answer (score 0):

`auto-fu` has not been updated 7 years. I cannot even get it to work with my current Zsh installation.

I would suggest you instead try out my plugin [`zsh-autocomplete`](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete), which does the same thing (and more!), but without any of the problems you mention. Also, I am actively developing and maintaining it. Please see the demo on the page I linked to for an impression of how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think I used a plugin for async completion with the same name before, not sure if it was yours. But I needed limited, yet very specific customized behavior for some widgets and completion contexts, which, if I remember correctly, was easier to do with autofu. I'll check yours out anyway.

Comment: @Bart And, did you try it?